# Controller stops working after moving to a different package

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, controller

I have a project which is lot of controllers some using annotations and some XML
configuration. they have components can set to `com.test`. When I moved the controller, package something like `com.test.p1` to `com.test.p2` it stopped working. I had to create a XML configuration for it. What should I look for in the XML configuration to fix this?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For annotated Controllers, use this in config 
`<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.p2" />`

For bean definitions, change the class attribute 
`<bean class="com.test.p2.className" >`